# Отображение нескольких окон на несколько мониторов

Tags: c#, wpf

При запуске приложения необходимо отобразить на 3 монитора - 3 разных окна.
`монитор А` > `окно А`
`монитор Б` > `окно Б`
`монитор В` > `окно В`
Примерно так.

Каким образом это можно реализовать на C# и WPF?

Comment: Как вы пробовали решить проблему?

Comment: @tym32167, я пробовал таким же образом, как описано ниже в ответе, но хотелось бы обойтись исключительно средствами WPF.

Comment: @Arthur Edgarov надеюсь, это как раз то, что вы искали...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вариант **БЕЗ WinForms**.

**ScreenInformation.cs**

```
namespace MultiScreen
{
    public class ScreenInformation
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct ScreenRect
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;
        }

        [DllImport("user32")]
        private static extern bool EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr lpRect, MonitorEnumProc callback, int dwData);

        private delegate bool MonitorEnumProc(IntPtr hDesktop, IntPtr hdc, ref ScreenRect pRect, int dwData);

        public class WpfScreen
        {
            public WpfScreen(ScreenRect prect)
            {
                metrics = prect;
            }

            public ScreenRect metrics;
        }

        static LinkedList<WpfScreen> allScreens = new LinkedList<WpfScreen>();

        public static LinkedList<WpfScreen> GetAllScreens()
        {
            ScreenInformation.GetMonitorCount();
            return allScreens;
        }

        public static int GetMonitorCount()
        {
            allScreens.Clear();
            int monCount = 0;
            MonitorEnumProc callback = (IntPtr hDesktop, IntPtr hdc, ref ScreenRect prect, int d) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Left {0}", prect.left);
                Console.WriteLine("Right {0}", prect.right);
                Console.WriteLine("Top {0}", prect.top);
                Console.WriteLine("Bottom {0}", prect.bottom);
                allScreens.AddLast(new WpfScreen(prect));
                return ++monCount > 0;
            };

            if (EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, callback, 0))
                Console.WriteLine("You have {0} monitors", monCount);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("An error occured while enumerating monitors");

            return monCount;
        }
    }
}
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
namespace MultiScreen
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            LinkedList<ScreenInformation.WpfScreen> screens = ScreenInformation.GetAllScreens();
            foreach (var screen in screens)
            {
                var window = new MainWindow();

                Console.WriteLine("Metrics {0} {1}", screen.metrics.top, screen.metrics.left);

                window.Top = screen.metrics.top;
                window.Left = screen.metrics.left;
                window.Show();
            }
        }                
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, именно это и нужно было.

Comment: Быть может вы могли бы мне подсказать, как я могу эмулировать работу с тремя мониторами в процессе создания программы? Так как у меня только ноутбук в наличии, а тестировать надо.

Comment: Способа эмулировать монитор нет. Можно, например, как-то расшарить монитор между устройствами, но если у вас в ноуте есть VGA ... то можно сделать так, что винда будет думать, что вы подключили второй монитор... Но в таком случае, вы не увидите формочку.  (http://www.overclock.net/t/384733/the-30-second-dummy-plug)

Comment: То есть, грубо говоря, разбить монитор ноутбука на 3 виртуальных "суб-монитора" не получится?

Comment: @Arthur Edgarov не уверен, что это вообще подошло бы для тестов =) , но вы можете попробовать это https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/use-your-android-device-as-second-monitor-for-your-windows-pc-0175646/. У меня просто 3 монитора и телевизор - я не парюсь =)

Comment: Ну хоть так, спасибо =)

Comment: @Arthur Edgarov как вариант, можно использовать виртуальную машину с несколькими мониторами. Как минимум VirtualBox позволяет создать до 8 виртуальных мониторов.

Comment: @IvanParfentev, понял, спасибо за подсказку.

Answer (score 5):

Можно использовать `System.Windows.Forms.Screen` класс, для того что бы определить кол-во мониторов и их параметры, и распределить окна по мониторам.

```
foreach (var screen in Screen.AllScreens)
{
    var window = new MyWindow();
    var workingArea = screen.WorkingArea;
    window.Top = workingArea.Top;
    window.Left = workingArea.Left;
    window.Show();
}
```

Таким образом откроется по окну на каждом мониторе.

Comment: А можно ли обойтись без System.Windows.Forms? Или это единственный способ?

Comment: @Arthur Edgarov можно без winforms. Но с ними проще ... почему их не хотите использовать?

Comment: @LexHobbit, да не хотелось бы смешивать, это ведь разные технологии... А как без winforms?

Comment: @Arthur Edgarov сейчас найду проект на работе и напишу ответ

Comment: @LexHobbit, было бы круто, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Под Mono работает?